# Update from 3.9.x to 4.x

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, update, migration, joomla-4.x

I want to try Joomla 4.x

In the documentation for [*Joomla 3.x to 4.x Step by Step Migration*](https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_3.x_to_4.x_Step_by_Step_Migration#Going_to_Joomla.21_4.x) it says:

> 4. Select Joomla Next (This is the current text - it may be different in the future) from the drop-down for Update server.
> 5. Click Save & Close.

I have done this, but it will only show the latest 3.x version.
What's wrong? What should I do to test the upgrade to 4.x ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for 3.10.X to become available; as per the documentation, "This guide assumes you are starting on Joomla 3.10.x. If you are on a earlier version make sure you upgrade to Joomla 3.10 first before moving to Joomla 4."

Joomla 3.10 is currently in development, at [86% completion](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/milestone/34), most notably, with no completion date for release. V3.10-dev can be found [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/3.10-dev) but is not yet available for updating via the Update process in your current Joomla 3.X installation.

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI that Joomla 3.10-alpha has now been released so the upgrade process can now easily done.

#### Instructions:

1. Go to the Joomla Update Component Options and switch the Update Channel to `Testing` and the Minimum Stability option to `Alpha`.
2. Update to 3.10 alpha1 using the Joomla Update Component.
3. After you have updated to 3.10 alpha please switch the Update
   Channel to `Custom URL` and set the Custom URL to `https://update.joomla.org/core/test/310to4_list.xml`
4. After the upgrade please switch back to the `Testing` Update Channel with the `Beta` minimum stability to get future updates between Joomla 4 betas.

Comment: As at 16th July, this didn't work for me and the following error was displayed instead: `We can't find a download URL` `An update to Joomla 4.0.0-rc4 was found, but it wasn't possible to download that update` I was able to upgrade to Joomla 4.0.0-rc5-dev using the nightly build Custom URL: https://update.joomla.org/core/nightlies/next_major_list.xml